# getBoundingClientRect().top returning wrong value

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Im using react js and Im trying to get the dom element value using getBoundingClientRect().top. Im using useEffect and inside im adding window.scrollY into getBoundingClientRect().top so that i always get the same value. But it returns wrong value. I tried logging just getBoundingClientRect().top and it gives me a value like 155 or something similar but the correct value is 2408. Code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(containerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().top);
}, []);

<div className="experience-containter">
  <div ref={containerRef} className="image-container-1">
    <div>
      <img src={image1} alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


.experience-containter {
  position: relative;

.image-container-1 {
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
border-radius: 50%;
position: absolute;
right: 15%;
overflow: hidden;

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  width: 140%;
  object-fit: cover;
  }
 }
}
```

Im using ref as you can see and trying to get the value containerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().top. Please help

Comment: can you please add the javascript part as well.

Comment: Im just logging its value in useEffect to check whether the value is correct or not. I have added the useEffect code

Answer (score 4):

getBoundingClientRect() return the value relative to the window (view port), so if you want to get exactly the position no matter how user scroll up and down, you'd better get value of getBoundingClientRect() PLUS the document coordinators.

For example using the function below

```js
// get document coordinates of the element
function getCoords(elem) {
  let box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

  return {
    top: box.top + window.pageYOffset,
    right: box.right + window.pageXOffset,
    bottom: box.bottom + window.pageYOffset,
    left: box.left + window.pageXOffset
  };
}
```

For more information, you can refer to the full document here
https://javascript.info/coordinates

Comment: This is by far the most accurate answer that works!
I have been crawling the web for the last few hours for a solution where none of them worked and I was hopeless for this to work either but turned out this was what I was looking for!
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using the `getBoundingClientRect().top` is the right way to approach scrolling to an element.
The `getBoundingClientRect()` function returns the bounding box relative to the window and not the entire webpage, so it might not give you the correct position of the element.

You can try using `containerRef.current.scrollIntoView()` to scroll the element to view. If you want to get the offset value you can try `containerRef.current.offsetTop + window.scrollY`

Comment: getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY is giving good result. The only issue I have is on the initial load the value is incorrect in chrome. In firefox, if i refresh 2, 3 times I get the right value. This does not make any sense why its happening.

Comment: I have tried offsetTop as well and same thing is happening. Google chrome just refuse to give the correct value but on firefox refreshing the page sometimes give correct and sometimes doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

For those, who come here from Google:

For me the combination of `getBoundingClientRect()` and offset values from `window` or `document` didn't work and I had to use an offset from html element itself:

```
getTopDistance(htmlElement) {
    return htmlElement.getBoundingClientRect() - htmlElement.offsetTop;
}
```

Comment: This is totally wrong. How do you substract a number from a struct? And what if there is an `offsetLeft` on the element?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem in Angular while using element.offsetTop() which does basically the same as .getBoundingClientRect().top.
When calling element.offsetTop within ngOnInit() it returned completely different (and wrong) values.

I solved it by calling it in ngAfterViewChecked(). This method is called last in the component lifecycle (https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).
It seems like offsetTop only works after the view is completely initialized.